# Need help for c# Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to create a Regex with named groups that matches all of the four following strings:

```
var club = "Real Madrid";
var city = "Madrid";
var nation = "Spain";

var string1 = club;
var string2 = club + "," + city;
var string3 = club + "(" + nation + ")";
var string4 = club + "," + city + "(" + nation + ")";
```

Or in other words:
String looks like `"club,city(nation)"` where city and nation are optional with optional whitespaces included.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What expressions have you tried so far?

Comment: Show something that you've looked into about regexs. For now it seems you just concatenating strings.

Comment: A nice tool for debugging your regular expressions is http://www.regexr.com/ . There is even a cheatsheet providing you with the right placeholders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex from aelor but added a "(" sign after "^(?[^," to match the string "Real Madrid(Spain)"

Added a code example too.

```
var strings = new List<string>() { "Real Madrid", "Real Madrid,Madrid", "Real Madrid(Spain)", "Real Madrid,Madrid(Spain)" };

foreach (var str in strings)
{
    var match = Regex.Match(str, @"^(?<club>[^,]+)(?:,(?<city>[^\(]+))?(?:\((?<nation>[^\)]+)\))?$");

    var name = match.Groups["club"].Value;
    var city = match.Groups["city"].Value;
    var country = match.Groups["nation"].Value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?<club>[^,]+)(?:,(?<city>[^\(]+))?(?:\((?<nation>[^\)]+)\))?$
```

i think this will serve your purpose for all the strings.

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/nV7pT7/2